# struct and typedef

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Are the following equivalent in C?

```
// #1
struct myStruct {
    int id;
    char value;
};

typedef struct myStruct Foo;

// #2
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char value;
} Foo;
```

If not, which one should I use and when?

(Yes, I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c).)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083959/purpose-of-struct-typedef-struct-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they're not exactly equivalent.

In the first version `Foo` is a typedef for the named `struct myStruct`.

In the second version, `Foo` is a `typedef` for an unnamed `struct`.

Although both `Foo` can be used in the same way in many instances there are important differences. In particular, the second version doesn't allow the use of a forward declaration to declare `Foo` and the `struct` it is a `typedef` for whereas the first would.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant to say `typedef struct myStruct Foo`

Comment: Thanks, can you show an example where the difference between them is apparent?

Comment: @pessimopoppotamus: Well like I said, the most obvious way is that in the first case you can use `typedef struct myStruct Foo;` to forward declare the `struct` and `Foo` and use it as an incomplete type (where appropriate) whereas this is just not possible with the unnamed `struct` version. You can also (of course) use `struct myStruct` as a name for the type in the first instance; there is no "full" version of the type in the second.

Answer (score 12):

The second option cannot reference itself. For example:

```
// Works:
struct LinkedListNode_ {
    void *value;
    struct LinkedListNode_ *next;
};

// Does not work:
typedef struct {
    void *value;
    LinkedListNode *next;
} LinkedListNode;

// Also Works:
typedef struct LinkedListNode_ {
    void *value;
    struct LinkedListNode_ *next;
} LinkedListNode;
```

Answer (score 3):

The first form allows you to refer to the struct before the type definition is complete, so you can refer to the struct within itself or have mutually dependent types:

```
struct node {
  int value;  
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
};

typedef struct node Tree;
```

or

```
struct A;
struct B;

struct A {
  struct B *b;
};

struct B {
  struct A *a;
};

typedef struct A AType;
typedef struct B Btype;
```

You can combine the two like so:

```
typedef struct node {
  int value;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
} Tree;

typedef struct A AType;  // You can create a typedef 
typedef struct B BType;  // for an incomplete type

struct A {
  BType *b;
};

struct B {
  AType *a;
};
```