# typedef struct and enum, why?

Tags: c++, enums, struct

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Purpose of struct, typedef struct, in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083959/purpose-of-struct-typedef-struct-in-c)
>   [typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

In code that I am maintaining I often see the following:

```
typedef enum { blah, blah } Foo;
typedef struct { blah blah } Bar;
```

Instead of:

```
enum Foo { blah, blah };
struct Bar { blah blah };
```

I always use the latter, and this is the first time I am seeing the former. So the question is why would one use one style over the other. Any benefits? Also are they functionally identical? I believe they are but am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++ this doesn't matter.

In C, `struct`s, `enum`s, and `union`s were in a different "namespace", meaning that their names could conflict with variable names. If you say

```
struct S { };
```

So you could say something like

```
struct S S;
```

and that would mean that `struct S` is the data type, and `S` is the variable name. You couldn't say

```
S myStruct;
```

in C if `S` was a `struct` (and not a type name), so people just used `typedef` to avoid saying `struct` all the time.

Comment: `enum`, `union`, and `struct` have the same issue.

Comment: Yea, I re-read your answer and realized that and then deleted my comment. Oops. Thanks!

Comment: @anio: Haha okay, no problem.

Answer (score 3):

They are for C compatability. A normal

```
  struct Bar { blah, blah };
```

doesn't work the same with C;