# Structures with typedef

Tags: c, struct, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Purpose of struct, typedef struct, in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083959/purpose-of-struct-typedef-struct-in-c)
>   [typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

I am aware that there are two ways of declaring structs in C

```
struct point{
    int x, y;
};
```

and:

```
typedef struct{
    int x, y;
} point;
```

but what is the difference between these two methods and when would I use the typedef method and not the other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way to declare a `struct` in *C*, using the `struct` keyword, optionally followed by the name of the structure, then followed by the member fields list in braces. So you could have:

```
  struct point_st {
     int x, y;
  };
```

Here `point_st` is the name (or tag) of your structure. Notice that structure names have a different namespace in C than types (this is different in C++). So I have the habit of suffixing structure names with `_st` as shown above.

You can (independently) define a type name using typedef, e.g.

```
  typedef struct point_st Point;
```

(you can use `typedef` on any C type, BTW).

For exemple Gtk and Glib has a lot of opaque types which are such opaque structures; only the implementation knows and cares about the structure members.

Of course the compiler needs to know the field of a structure to allocate it; but if you only use pointers to an opaque structure, you don't need to declare the structure (i.e. its fields in braces).

Answer (score 2):

differences:

1. The first one is valid C89;
2. The first one doesn't make the label of the struct ("point") to be a complete type definition, so you can use `point p;` with the second one only.
3. Our C programming God, Linus Torvalds strongly encourages **not using** typedefs for structs (except if there's an explicit need for hiding the actual fields and type behind an opaque struct) as it diminishes readability.

Comment: Do you have a reference/link for the `strongly encourages not using typedefs for structs` part? . . . And another one for the `Our C programming God, Linus Torvalds`? . . .

Comment: @paercebal http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle

Answer (score 0):

With first form, variable declaration must be:

```
struct point A;
```

Second form allows to declare variables without `struct` like

```
point B;
```